# Create different versions of XML files recursively based on prior retrieved paths

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, elementtree

I am having trouble writing certain nodes text into an xml file. I have a xml file which i need to modify by creating different versions (0,000s) of the original file. A pseudo file is given below.

```
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <language>english</language>
    <currency>1.21$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc month="06">141100</gdppc>
    <gdpnp month="10">2.304e+0150</gdpnp>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <language>english</language>
    <currency>4.1$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc month="05">59900</gdppc>
    <gdpnp month="08">5.2e-015</gdpnp>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
```

I have been able to retrieve these qualified text nodes and their paths using the code given below.

```
def extractNumbers(path, node):
    nums = []

if 'month' in node.attrib:
    if node.attrib['month'] in ['05', '06']:
        return nums
    path += '/' + node.tag
    if 'name' in node.keys():
        path += '=' + node.attrib['name']

    try:
        num = float(node.text)
        nums.append( (path, num) )
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        pass

    for e in list(node):
        nums.extend( extractNumbers(path, e) )

    return nums

tree = ET.parse('jerry.xml')
nums = extractNumbers('', tree.getroot())
print len(nums)
print nums
```

An example of one such path and value is given below

`('/data/country name=Singapore/gdpnp month=08', 5.2e-015`

I now need to read in a modified form of the value `5.2e-015`, say `2*5.2e-015` into the xml file based on the above path? I need to create 0,000 of these files. What is the best way to approach this or has anyone previously implemented this?

Comment: Your question is so unclear it's hard to know where to begin to help you.   Try including a representative sample of your XML input files.  Try showing your desired output.   Try explaining your "path" notation, or preferably, use a standard notation instead.  Try showing some  python code.

Comment: Thanks, I included a sample xml file and added more details to the question.

Comment: The question is still unclear. The problem seems to be about modifying some XML ("read in a modified form" of a value), but the code in the question does not attempt to do that. Where are you stuck? What does "I need to create 0,000 of these files" mean? Thousands of files?